# How do i get the absolute position of the div?

Tags: jquery

I want to store the absolute position of my div's. I've made a foreach that targets them all but what function do I use? `.position()` returns relative to parent, but is `.offset` the right one if I want the absolute position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With javascript i think you can do like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("id").offsetLeft;
var y = document.getElementById("id").offsetTop
```

And with jQuery you can use [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset)

Hugs

Comment: That's good, but both of those are jQuery.  There's no $(...) syntax in javascript.

Comment: Oh yes, thats true, i made a confusion... I'll edit this... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. I would check out these links:

http://api.jquery.com/position/

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you want position relative to the `document` - [API](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)